# Regular expression to match headers and sub headers followed by a bullet list

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture the text in headers/subsections and the bullet list that follows it with:

```
re.finditer('(?!^\* )(?P<description>^.+?)(?P<items>^\* .+?^)(?!^\* )', 
            text, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

with this sample text:

```
Header A
Subheader A
* Item A
* Item B
* Item C
Header B
Subheader B
Description B
* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3
Random Header C
* Item X
* Item Y
* Item Z
```

The expression works except on `Random Header C` and its bullet list. A workaround is to add two trailing line breaks `\n\n` after `* Item F`. Any idea how to match the last section or if there is a better method for doing this?

https://regex101.com/r/yG7sJ6/1

Comment: This shouldn't be flagged python. `re.match` stops matching after `*Item C`. https://bpaste.net/show/25508eb4d2a5

Comment: @bschlueter I should have specified I was using `re.finditer`.

Comment: Aha, might I suggest rephrasing your question so that it will be clearer to others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture missing items:

```
(?P<description>^.+?)(?P<items>(?:^\* [^\n]+(?:\n|$))+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yG7sJ6/3)